# Merge/Join two separate graphs algorithm?

Tags: java, graph, finite-automata

i Need an algorithm for merging or joining to graphs, by this I mean that the last node of graph 1 should be predecesor of first node of graph 2. 
Graph 1:

```
1->2->3
   \ /
    4->5
```

Graph 2:

```
6->7
   | \
   8->9
```

This is what I need:

```
1->2->3
   \ /
    4->5->6->7
             | \
             8->9
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, i am aware that I can traverse the secondgraph and add every single node to the first one, also the edges, but i was wondering if there is some predefined algorythm which will make it easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

createNewGraph
iterate graph 1 and add new graph
iterate graph 1
    for each node iteratesuccessors
        for each edge between these nodes add to the new graph

iterate graph 2 and add new graph
iterate graph 2
    for each node iteratesuccessors
        for each edge between these nodes add to the new graph

add edge from last node of graph 1 to firstnode of graph 2

Answer (score 0):

1. Scan the vertices of graph 1, and find a vertex of [outdegree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph#Indegree_and_outdegree) zero.
2. Scan the vertices of graph 2, and find a vertex of [indegree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph#Indegree_and_outdegree) zero.
3. Connect the two vertices with an arc.

Depending on the graphs, the solution may or may not be unique (it is unique in the example that you give).

Comment: I already have the nodes specified which needs to connect, this is my method: concat(DirectedGraphInterface g1, DirectedGraphInterface g2). I am using yEd grail with java

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on how you represent the graphs. For instance, if the nodes are numbered as in your example (`1..N` for the first graph, `N+1..M` for the second graph), all you need to do is create a new graph, copy both your graphs to the new one, and add edge `N,N+1` to it.